# Youtube iframe not playing within a certain domain - why?

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api, youtubeplayer

We are a motorsport media outlet (the biggest in Germany). When embedding videos (any video!) from youtube, for some reason, this doesn’t work anymore.

"debug_error": "{"errorCode":"auth","errorDetail":"0","errorMessage":"Video nicht verfügbar","Ak":"Dieses Video darf nicht auf dieser Domain gezeigt werden","NQ":"0;a6s.0","hB":2}",

The same video embedded on our “sister”-page https://www.formel1.de is working correctly. So, the reason for the error CANNOT be the video itself.

I made some test pages
OK: https://www.formel1.de/ytembedtest.html
OK: https://www.ms-total.com/ytembedtest.html
NOT OK: https://www.motorsport-total.com/ytembedtest.html
(The source is always identical)

Here's a video what's happening when we're trying it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DdZfJai3qA

How can we fix it? Who is to contact? Please help Google!

Comment: On my side the embed video [jh9raOS884g](https://youtu.be/jh9raOS884g) on [the link your shared](https://www.motorsport-total.com/gt-world-challenge/news/podium-rueckt-naeher-valentino-rossi-holt-in-misano-bestes-sprint-resultat-22070403) works. Am I missing something ?

Comment: So when you press "play" the video starts? That would be surprising. For me, the error occurs - and for all colleagues it's the same

Comment: I recorded [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugTtHYdxALM) to show you how I see, correctly IMO, both links I sent using a Firefox private window from a Switzerland IP.

Comment: I'm baffled, @BenjaminLoison :) Even if I try it with swiss VPN - no change. Could you please check the links in the edited version of the question? I provided three links to test embeds and a video of what we see when trying it

Comment: On my side the embed video [jh9raOS884g](https://youtu.be/jh9raOS884g) on [the link your shared](https://www.motorsport-total.com/gt-world-challenge/news/podium-rueckt-naeher-valentino-rossi-holt-in-misano-bestes-sprint-resultat-22070403) **still** works. However I get "Video unavailable
This video is restricted from being viewed on this domain
Watch on YouTube" on https://www.motorsport-total.com/ytembedtest.html

Comment: @BenjaminLoison - Still have no explanation for this. BUT: The embeds on the news page are a bit different. There is another domain (ms-total.com) involved, because the "ban" on the main domain lasts a bit longer. This workaround (embed through embed) worked until some days ago - and for you it still works. 
What you could look at: In dev tools, catch the the call to "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/youtubei/v1/player", in the payload, what does stand in your request at: playbackContext->contentPlaybackContext->ancestorOrigins?

Comment: For this request when clicking the YouTube video I have `[]` as the value of `playbackContext->contentPlaybackContext->ancestorOrigins`

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Ooooh, thank you. It doesn't remove the ban - but the old way of embed through embed is working again with a header to prevent referrers to be sent. That is good! Thanks! (I guess you're browser didn't send a referrer in this case, that's why you could see the video.)
But the fundamental problem stays the same. If motorsport-total.com is a referrer, videos are blocked