# Get rid of domain ban for youtube iframe

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api, youtubeplayer

Somehow we managed to get a domain ban for iframe embeds of youtube videos - and find NO WAY to get it lifted!

The error is this:
`"debug_error": "{"errorCode":"auth","errorDetail":"0","errorMessage":"Video nicht verfügbar","Ak":"Dieses Video darf nicht auf dieser Domain gezeigt werden","NQ":"0;a6s.0","hB":2}",`

The same video embedded on our “sister”-page https://www.formel1.de is working correctly. So, the reason for the error CANNOT be the video itself.

I made some test pages
OK: https://www.formel1.de/ytembedtest.html

OK: https://www.ms-total.com/ytembedtest.html

NOT OK: https://www.motorsport-total.com/ytembedtest.html
(The source is always identical)

You can lift the ban? Who is to contact?

Comment: Question following [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73052056).

Answer (score 1):

We had some intermittent issue with "Video Unavailable, Watch on youtube" embeds

You could try the following chaging youtube.com to [www.youtube-nocookie.com](http://www.youtube-nocookie.com) and adding referrerpolicy="strict-origin" to your embeds.

e.g.

```
<iframe width="620" height="349" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Hu0_TOybRx0?autoplay=0&origin=http://www.motorsport-total.com" style=""></iframe>
```

becomes

```
<iframe width="620" height="349" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/Hu0_TOybRx0?autoplay=0&origin=http://www.motorsport-total.com" style="" referrerpolicy="strict-origin"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify that your website complies with Youtube's policies, you can do so by requesting a compliance audit here: https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form (Yes, I know that this form seems unrelated, but this form is actually a catch-all for most API-related issues.)

and you can file an actual appeal here: https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_appeals

More information:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies

You might also want to verify that your settings, if you have any, on https://studio.youtube.com/ and the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/youtubeembeddedplayer.googleapis.com) are correct, though it seems unlikely to be related.

Good luck!